# How to make only two buttons active in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

In my code, there is a condition that pops up the following dialog:

[image]

Its code looks like this:

```dart
  //Alert Dialog about questions and answers
  void _showAlertDialog() {

    // set up the buttons
    Widget Answer1Button = TextButton(
      child: Text(_listData[_listCount][3]),
      onPressed:  () {},
    );
    Widget Answer2Button = TextButton(
      child: Text(_listData[_listCount][4]),
      onPressed:  () {},
    );

    // set up the AlertDialog
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      // title: Text(),
      content: Text(_listData[_listCount][2]),
      actions: [
        Answer1Button,
        Answer2Button,
      ],
    );

    // show the dialog
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }
```

I need my user to not be able to tap on the screen or press the back button. Only two buttons need to be active (Answer 1.1 and Answer 1.2 in this example).

How to do it? Thanks in advance.

**Edit1.** I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code where I followed your advice:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          await showDialog;
          // await showDialog or Show add banners or whatever
          // return true if the route to be popped
          return false; // return false if you want to disable device back button click
        },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('New Game'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage(assetPath),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover)),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Visibility(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                      child: Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Positioned.fill(
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                      image: AssetImage('files/sheet.jpg'),
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(_listData[_listCount][0]),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: [
                        ImageButton(label: 'OK', onButtonTap: _nextCSV),
                        ImageButton(label: 'Hide', onButtonTap: _isVisible),
                        ImageButton(label: 'Test1', onButtonTap: _showAlertDialog),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                visible: isVisible,
              ),
              // your other widgets
              Visibility(
                child: ImageButton(label: 'Show', onButtonTap: _isVisible),
                visible: !isVisible,
              )

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

But nothing has changed. I believe that I made a mistake here:

```dart
await showDialog;
```

However, when I do like this, nothing changes either. The back button still works:

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          return false; // return false if you want to disable device back button click
        },
      child: Scaffold(
...
```

As a result, I can still click on the back button. Although I want it to be inactive on the dialog. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap the AlertDialog with OnWillPop, not the Scaffold, since you need to set the action pop for the AlertDialog widget.

Here's a minimal example of how to implement the OnWillPop widget to match your case:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _showAlertDialog();
              },
              style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
              ),
              child: const Text(
                "Open Dialog",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ))),
    );
  }

  void _showAlertDialog() {
    // set up the buttons
    Widget Answer1Button = TextButton(
      child: Text("Button 1"),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
    );
    Widget Answer2Button = TextButton(
      child: Text("Button 2"),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
    );

    // set up the AlertDialog
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      // title: Text(),
      content: Text("Alert Dialog"),
      actions: [
        Answer1Button,
        Answer2Button,
      ],
    );

    // show the dialog
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: () async {
              return false;
            },
            child: alert);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works exactly as it should. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a parameter named 'barrierDismissible' in the showDialog, set it to false.

```
showDialog(
  barrierDismissible: false,
  builder: ...
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this partially solves my problem. But when using this parameter, my user can still press the back button, which breaks the logic of my application.

How can I make the back button also disabled when this dialog appears?

Comment: I have edited the answer to disable back button. Please check the answer and verify if it is helpful for you.

Comment: Please, look at my Edit1. I am a beginner so even after I followed all the instructions I don't see any change.

Comment: I dont get you. Could you explain on how can I help you?

Comment: I mean I want to disable back button by wrapping the Scaffold with WillPopScope. I did this (my code is in Edit1). But when the dialog box appears, the back button is still active. What's my mistake?

Comment: Back button will be active, but it will not perform any action on pressing.

Answer (score 0):

There is one parameter called `barrierDismissible` which you can use to dismiss any tap of background of dialog,

```
showDialog(
  barrierDismissible: false,
)
```

You can disable back button by wrapping the scaffold with  WillPopScope.

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async {
        // await showDialog or Show add banners or whatever
        // return true if the route to be popped
         return false; // return false if you want to disable device back button click
       },
      child: Scaffold(),
     ),
  };
```

Here is the docs links
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html

Comment: Thank you. This works great. Can you elaborate on the WillPopScope widget? I still don't understand how to make the back button also disabled when this dialog box appears.

Comment: @Texter A good person have edited the answer to provide more info and also I have added the docs link which you can refer to

Comment: Please, look at my Edit1. I am a beginner so even after I followed all the instructions I don't see any change.